# Output is not producing expected outcome

Tags: c#, overloading, constructor-chaining

This is my code:

```
class StockItem
{
    internal float CostPrice;
    internal string Description;
    internal static int LastStockNumber = 10000;
    internal int StockNumber;

    public StockItem(int StockNumber, string Description, float CostPrice): this(Description, CostPrice)
    {
        this.StockNumber = StockNumber;
    }

    public StockItem(string Description, float CostPrice)
    {
        LastStockNumber++;
        this.StockNumber = LastStockNumber;
        this.CostPrice = CostPrice;
        this.Description = Description;
    }

    public float GetCostPrice()
    {
        return CostPrice;
    }

    public virtual string Print() //is virtual (Polymorphic)
    {
        string Output = "";
        Output += "\r\n\r\n";
        Output += "Stock Item: ";
        Output += "\r\n";
        Output += "Stock No: " + StockNumber;
        Output += "\r\n";
        Output += "Desc: " + Description;
        Output += "\r\n";
        Output += "Cost: " + CostPrice;
        Output += "\r\n";
        return Output;
      }
    }
}

class HeavyStockItem : StockItem
{
    internal float Weight;

    public HeavyStockItem(int StockNumber, string Description, float CostPrice, float Weight)
        : base(StockNumber, Description, CostPrice)
    {
        this.Weight = Weight;
    }

    public HeavyStockItem(string Description, float CostPrice, float Weight)
        : base(Description, CostPrice)
    {
        LastStockNumber++;
        this.StockNumber = LastStockNumber;
        this.Weight = Weight;
    }

    public float GetWeight()
    {
        return Weight;
    }

    public override String Print() //overriding StockItem.Print and adds wieght to the bottom 
    {
        string Output = "";
        Output += base.Print();
        Output += "Weight: " + Weight + "\r\n";
        return Output;
      }
    }
}

class CarEngine : HeavyStockItem
{
    internal string EngineNumber;

    public CarEngine(int StockNumber, string Description, float CostPrice, float Weight, string EngineNumber)
        : base(StockNumber, Description, CostPrice, Weight)
    {
        this.EngineNumber = EngineNumber;
    }

    public CarEngine(string Description, float CostPrice, float Weight, string EngineNumber)
        : base(Description, CostPrice, Weight)
    {
        LastStockNumber++;
        this.StockNumber = LastStockNumber;
    }

    public override String Print() //overriding StockItem.Print and adds engine number to the bottom 
    {
        string Output = "";
        Output += base.Print();
        Output += "EngineNumber: " + EngineNumber + "\r\n";
        return Output;
    }
  }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    StockItem StockItem1;
    CarEngine StockItem2;
    CarEngine StockItem3;
    StockItem StockItem4;
    HeavyStockItem StockItem5;

    private void ShowItem (StockItem PrintStockItem)
    {
        txtOutput.Text += PrintStockItem.Print();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StockItem1 = new StockItem(StockItem.LastStockNumber, "Scrediwer set", 42);
        StockItem2 = new CarEngine(8025, "MazdaB6T", 1252, 800, "Z4537298D");
        StockItem3 = new CarEngine(StockItem.LastStockNumber, "Holden 308", 958, 1104, "P74623854S");
        StockItem4 = new StockItem(8002, "Trolley Jack", 127);
        StockItem5 = new HeavyStockItem(HeavyStockItem.LastStockNumber, "JD Caterpillar Track", 3820, 2830);
    }

    private void btnList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //polymorfic call
    {
        ShowItem(StockItem1);
        ShowItem(StockItem2);
        ShowItem(StockItem3);
        ShowItem(StockItem4);
        ShowItem(StockItem5);
    }
  }
}
```

This is my output:

```
Stock Item: 
Stock No: 10000
Desc: Scrediwer set
Cost: 42

Stock Item: 
Stock No: 8025
Desc: MazdaB6T
Cost: 1252
Weight: 800
EngineNumber: Z4537298D

Stock Item: 
Stock No: 10002
Desc: Holden 308
Cost: 958
Weight: 1104
EngineNumber: P74623854S

Stock Item: 
Stock No: 8002
Desc: Trolley Jack
Cost: 127

Stock Item: 
Stock No: 10004
Desc: JD Caterpillar Track
Cost: 3820
Weight: 2830
```

My question is :

Instead of getting Stock No for items 1,3 & 5 to be 10000, 10001 & 10002 I am getting as per above. Cant Understand Why?

Comment: That is a lot of code to read through. Are you able to condense this to show only relevant information? You might be able to solve it by yourself if you do.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor for `StockItem` that accepts a specific StockNumber is calling the *other* constructor that increments `LastStockNumber`. Therefore, every time you create an instance of `StockItem` (or something that derives from `StockItem`), the `LastStockNumber` will be incremented, even if a stock number was specified in the constructor.

In fact, you are incrementing `LastStockNumber` in many of the constructors, which would lead to it being incremented at least twice when you create some types of objects.

---

**Edit:**

As for how to fix this, I'd start by changing the `StockItem` constructor that uses the LastStockNumber so that rather than calling the other constructor, it just sets the price and description itself:

```
public StockItem(int StockNumber, string Description, float CostPrice)
{
    this.StockNumber = StockNumber;
    this.CostPrice = CostPrice;
    this.Description = Description;
}
```

Then I'd remove everywhere else that you increment the `LastStockNumber` in the constructors of the derived classes.

You should also make `LastStockNumber` private. After making those changes, if you continue to create the objects the way that you are, the `LastStockNumber` would never be incremented, because you are always specifying the stock number when you create the object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I see the problem just to figure out how to fix it!!!!

Comment: These are the requirements I have to meet"

Comment: - StockItem contains a static field which maintains the value of the last stock number used (initialised to 10000)

Comment: - One of StockItem's constructors ignores this field and receives the stock number as a parameter;it also receives the Description and CostPrice parameters.

Comment: - The second StockItem constructor uses the static field to automatically generate a StockNumber argument passed. It just receives Descriptions and CostPrice parameters.

Comment: That is why I must have two constructors in all classes(requirement).

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of `CarEngine` you are calling,

```
    StockItem2 = new CarEngine(8025, "MazdaB6T", 1252, 800, "Z4537298D");
```

is

```
public CarEngine(int StockNumber, string Description, float CostPrice, 
                 float Weight, string EngineNumber)
    : base(StockNumber, Description, CostPrice, Weight)
```

Which in turn calls the below base class constructor:

```
public StockItem(int StockNumber, string Description, float CostPrice): this(Description, CostPrice)
{
   this.StockNumber = StockNumber;
```

Which sets the StockNumber directly.

Similarly, the Trolley is constructed directly using the same StockItem constructor:

```
  StockItem4 = new StockItem(8002, "Trolley Jack", 127);
```

Seemingly, you wanted to call the other StockItem constructor, viz the one which increments the static counter:

```
 public StockItem(string Description, float CostPrice)
```

As an aside, note that you'll likely encounter rounding issues if you use floating point variables to store currency, e.g. `float CostPrice`. I would recommend using `decimal` instead.

**Edit**

FWIW I would redesign your base `StockItem` class as follows, to encapsulate the properties, and to take control over the allocation of Incrementing stock numbers. Also note that static variables are prone to thread safety issues.

```
internal class StockItem
{
    // Private to prevent externals + subclasses from mutating this
    private static int _lastStockNumber = 10000;

    // Convert to properties and private setters force subclasses to use the Ctor
    public decimal CostPrice { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }
    public int StockNumber { get; private set; }

    // Static is now read only
    public static int LastStockNumber
    {
        get { return _lastStockNumber; }
    }

    // Constructor not allowing for setting of Stock Number
    public StockItem(string description, decimal costPrice)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _lastStockNumber);
        this.CostPrice = costPrice;
        this.Description = description;
    }

    // Constructor allowing for direct setting of stockNumber
    public StockItem(int stockNumber, string description, decimal costPrice)
    {
        this.StockNumber = stockNumber;
        this.CostPrice = costPrice;
        this.Description = description;
    }
}
```

The above will force subclasses to use one of the constructors above to set the base class properties, and, if applicable, to auto-assign the StockNumber from the static in a more controlled and thread safe fashion.

Finally, the base classes can also make use of auto properties, instead of explicit getter methods, i.e. replace

```
public float GetWeight()
{
    return Weight;
}
```

with

```
public Weight {get; private set;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort StuartLC and your help as well; however, I am limited with what I can do or code with the checkpoint requirements, for example:

Comment: Thanks for the effort StuartLC and your help as well; however, I am limited with what I can do or code with the checkpoint requirements, for example:  in the StockItem class I can have CostPrice, Description, LastStockNumber and StockNumberFields and getCostPrice, Print and StockItemMethods. I can't add anything else.  Anyway I will work around your suggestions.